# Setting up self hosted CDN

Tags: cdn

Am building a site that makes a lot of requests for javascript and css files, and I've being reading about CDNs. I have a spare domain name and hosting space which I would like to use host these static files. My main domain is hosted on shared linux box with control panel.
How do I go about setting the CDN

Comment: Do you really mean a CDN? As in a global network of servers connected to key internet points? Or do you just want a cookieless domain?

Comment: @sam yes a cookieless domain

Answer (score 2):

You don't, unless your site scales beyond a point where you start to experience performance issues because it is overloaded.

The reason for this is simple: Having resources on a CDN requires the client's browser to start an additional session, complete with DNS lookup and everything, to download them. This usually costs performance.

Beyond that, a content delivery network basically is just a fancy name for a second (third, fourth...) server: Load your main site from http://example.com and reference the static content from http://cdn-example.com. On a large scale, there is obviously more to it, but that's the fundamental.

Something else: Having to load a lot of resource files is usually a sign of weak site design: Try to combine your resources into as few files as possible. It should usually be possible to condense all your JS and CSS in only a few files.

Comment: Browsers only open a certain number of connections per host.  By having files spread (e.g. some on a CDN) will open more connections, thus loading the page faste.  The DNS lookup is a small price worth paying.

Comment: And often-used resources (like jQuery) get cached a single time when many sites use the same CDN, this is another advantage